# Material design form required pattern

Tags: html, regex, angular, material-design

I want to have a required pattern for my fields, but the regex's I'm using aren't working & can't figure out why. I also want to center my 'onboard' button. here is a stackblitz link to my code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hpmxym?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

the required patterns I would like are as followed:
first name/last name: letters only, max 30
phone number: numbers only, max 10
zip: numbers only max 5
address: numbers and lettters only
city/state: letters only

and button center

Comment: use reactive form model it will easy to add such validaion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use template driven validation then you can leverage the `ngModel` to capture the value of element and perform the validation. Here is the sample code -

```
<input maxlength="5" type="text" name="zip" #zip="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="zipCode" required pattern="^\d{5,6}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$" placeholder="Zipcode" />
```

To make the button or control centered, you can wrap it inside div as

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <input type="submit" name="signup_submit" value="onboard" (click)="changeView(15)"/>
```

and use css

```
.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Sample working demo is here . - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1jdtpv

Comment: Demo is implemented with one field `zip` only. You could see the errors beneath the input. You can format the error message as per your requirement.

Comment: yeah but the zip field still allows for over 5 digits, letters, and special characters.

Comment: As per regex it working fine. It will accept `5-6` numbers or it can accept the format like `12345-1234`.  If you enter wrong format then you can see the `pattern` error on screen otherwise you will see `null` value means no error.

Comment: yeah but i want the cursor to stop when it reaches 5 digits, and i dont want letters to be allowed to be entered at all

Comment: You can use `maxlength="5" ` in element. Updated the link.

Comment: thank you! that was more of what I was looking for, and as far as letter, is there no way to just disallow them from the start?

Comment: If you just want to allow number only then you can use `type="number" `. Check the updated demo.

Comment: okay thanks for all your help. what about my button? tried using position: center but no lucj

Comment: Updated the answer and link.